# How to dismiss initial account manager dialog in google plus android?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, google-plus, android-dialog

Hi I am using google plus. when I click button, it need to display email and other information. But problem is if user has multiple account, without clicking button, dialog is opening. After dismissing dialog and click button, once again dialog is opening and working fine. I couldn't find this strange issue.
When i launch screen, without clicking button, choose an account dialog is opening. How to solve this?

Here is my code: I am using fragments.

```
 public class LoginFragment extends SherlockFragment implements   OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Common.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

    Common.mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    return view;
}
 public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (Common.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Common.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    }
    }
     Common:
     public class Common {
     static int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
     static String TAG = "MainActivity";
     static int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
     static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
     static boolean mIntentInProgress;
      static boolean mSignInClicked;
      static ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
      static Activity con;
      public Common(Activity c) {
      con = c;
       }
```

LoginActivity:

```
      public class LoginActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    public void resolveSignInError() {
    if (Common.mConnectionResult != null) {
        if (Common.mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                Common.mIntentInProgress = true;
                Common.mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        Common.con, Common.RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Common.mIntentInProgress = false;
                Common.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Common.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != Common.con.RESULT_OK) {
            Common.mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        Common.mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!Common.mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            Common.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Here is screenshot where without clicking google plus button, dialog pop up.

[image]

Comment: were you able to fix this, i am also struck with the same problem

Comment: did you got your fix ?

Comment: i am also struck with same problem. Do you have any solution?